When to forward reference a class and when to include a header file?
I have been learning about OOPs in C++ and I am not sure when should I forward reference a class and when should I include a header file. I understand that forward reference is useful when there can be a circular dependency. This leads me to another question, can I just forward reference everywhere? I don't see a downside to forward referencing a class but there seem to be problems regarding when and where to include a header file.
This question was derived from a project. I was told to include a class. So I did, "include class" but the answer was "class something" (Essentially forward referencing).

You can only forward declare incomplete types. See the linked question for a detailed explanation.

There are also problems with forward declaring as most uses of a class are not possible if all you have is a forward declaration (the notable exception is that you can declare a pointer or reference to a class based on just a forward declaration).

If you only want to declare variables that are pointers or references to objects of the class, then you can live with only forward declarations. If you need to actually "use" the objects (using member variables or functions, create object of the class, etc.) then you need the full class definition and to include the header file it's defined in.

The two main reasons for forward declaring are to break cyclic dependencies and to (hopefully) speed up compilation by not including so many header files. If neither of these are a concern then just include the header file.

Forward declaration: When you only need to know the type exists and do not need to know any details about it's space. For example taking a reference or pointer.
Include: When you need to know the details of it's space (storing it directly as a field) or when you need to know it's API (calling member functions)
